# Splitting Huge File into multiple files by date and time

Tags: java

I am splitting a huge file(2GB) into multiple files by date and time (12hrs for each file). But while splitting into multiple files, it is creating only some files.

```
20131101053000.txt
20131101173001.txt
20131102053002.txt
20131102173003.txt
20131103053004.txt
after that some more files to be created, but not creating.
```

Split File(**Updated**):

```
splitByDatenTime(timeFrameMillis, fstream); --> exception at line 30 in main method

private static void splitByDatenTime(long millis, DataInputStream fstream) {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
    FileWriter fstream1 = null;
    BufferedWriter out = null;
    String strLine = null;
    Date prevDate = null;
    Date currDate = null;
    String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    try {
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+;.+");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(strLine);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                String dateString = strLine.substring(0, 10);
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

                cal.setTimeInMillis(Long.valueOf(dateString) * 1000); --> exception at line 54

                currDate = cal.getTime();
                String currentDate = sdf.format(currDate);
                currDate = sdf.parse(currentDate);
                if (((prevDate == null) && (prevDate = currDate) != null)
                        || (prevDate.getTime() + millis < currDate
                                .getTime())) {

                    currentDate = currentDate.replaceAll("-|:", "");

                    fstream1 = new FileWriter(
                            "D:/Splited AIS Data3/"
                                    + currentDate + ".txt");
                    close(out);
                    out = new BufferedWriter(fstream1);
                    prevDate = currDate;
                }
                out.write(strLine);
                out.newLine();
            }
        }
        fstream1.close();
        close(out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Getting the NumberFormatException

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "!ABVDM,2,2"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:430)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
    at com.imu.examples.SplitFile1.splitByDatenTime(SplitFile1.java:54)
    at com.imu.examples.SplitFile1.main(SplitFile1.java:30)
```

Where is the problem i am not able to find. Please help me.
Thanks in Adance

Comment: You close the last file, but not the earlier ones. Is the last file complete?

Comment: yes the last one is complete

Comment: "!ABVDM,2,2" does not look like a long. Where does it come from, and why are you parsing it as a long? With the try-catch outside the loop, the exception is going to stop further operations. There is no file close in the catch block.

Comment: If non-parsable dateString values are something you have to handle, you need to reconsider the nesting of your try-catch blocks relative to the main loop.

Comment: Actually it is parsing for some part, after that it is not working where i need to change.It is already under try catch block

Comment: It is not enough to just have an arbitrarily placed try-catch. To get the logic to work correctly it is just as important to have the correct nesting of the try-catch relative to other code as to have correct nesting of other types of blocks. Think about the flow after the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close each file before overwriting `out`, to ensure its data gets written completely. As currently coded, only the last one gets closed.

Comment: It is not splitting the complete file, splitting only some files

Comment: Help me, not able find the reason why it is not reading the complete file

Comment: @spt Are you now closing each output file before going on to the next file?

Comment: Yes closing each file

Comment: First, if you have not done so already, use e.g. logging of the number of lines written to each file to check whether the issue is in the reading, selection, or writing. Once you have done that, I suggest writing a new question with your modified code and whatever information you have about the problem.

Comment: @Patrica Shanaham It is working fine with other file(500 mb), trying for 2 GB file it is not writing all.

Comment: @spt Any exceptions? I see in your code that you do print stack traces for them. Exactly how big is the "2 GB" file?

Comment: @Patrica Shanaham I am getting only one exception, and file of size 2GB.

Comment: Please update the question to clearly indicate the line where you are getting the exception. Also, note that "2GB" is ambiguous in this context. Do you mean 2,000,000,000 bytes or 2,147,483,648 bytes?

Comment: I have updated my question, the file size is 2,147,483,648 bytes.